# Copy folders from VM gcp to local machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I see some question here but no work fo me, i think is a sintaxe error:

In my instance :

```
ss@si:~/public_html/msite.com$
```

I have some folders:

```
folder1 folder2 folder3
```

I need copy all folders to my local machine so i try, run the comand in my local machine.

```
$gcloud init
```

After i answer some question i go to prompt again, amd try run:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse ss@si:~/public_html/msite.com/* magicnt@debian:/var/www/html/local-folder/ --zone southamerica-east1-a --project xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And get error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) All sources must be local files when destination is remote.
```

So my doubts are:

To copy from vm to local machine i need run the command in vm or local machine?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to specify destination without machine name, just a path to local folder.
Not a

> magicnt@debian:/var/www/html/local-folder/

but

> /var/www/html/local-folder/

Then your complete command should be:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse ss@si:~/public_html/msite.com/* /var/www/html/local-folder/ --zone southamerica-east1-a --project xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

See "gcloud compute scp" help example:

> To copy a remote directory, ~/narnia, from example-instance to the
>       ~/wardrobe directory of your local host, run:
>
> ```
>     $ gcloud compute scp --recurse example-instance:~/narnia ~/wardrobe
> ```